# Cannot find accounts while using personal.listAccounts

Tags: go-ethereum, console, cli

While following this [udemy tutorial](https://www.udemy.com/ethereum-dapp) and configuring the geth client I am presented with the following problem. The instructor hasn't responded yet so I thought I should ask here.

The thing is, on invoking **personal.listAccounts** , the console showed his account address but in my case nothing is being shown. I'm sure I did not skip over anything and the fact that our geth versions are slightly different bothers me in the sense that a few of the commands and options used simply do not work anymore in the latest version 1.8.15

What should I do to make sure that **personal.listAccounts** shows my address. I already have an account created in Ropsten and Rinkeby networks using metamask.
[image]

Comment: Did you call `personal.newAccount()` first?

Comment: Nope. He did not state that I should use that. I'm just learning this so I'm almost completely dependent on the material but that worked! After calling `personal.newAccount()` I had to put in a passphrase and then when i called `personal.listAccounts` it worked!. Thanks

Comment: It's likely that he had already created accounts in the past, so just assumed they exist. Most people have a few lying around if they're running nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, I had to call `personal.newAccount()` and create a new account. Since it is my first try this was necessary. After putting in the new account password and confirming it, I then called `personal.listAccounts` and I could see it in the array. Thanks to @Raghav Sood